# Defining a position function that is dependant on time:

Tags: javascript, function, p5.js

I am creating a simulation of 5 free falling balls that bounce with one another. I have the collision detection and the collisions done. But I am having trouble with defining the typical free falling equation. I have tried a lot of approaches but my knowledge is pretty limited. I would also like help with better coding practices.

```js
let bola1;
let bola2;
let bola3;
let bola4;
let bola5;

class Bola{
  constructor(y,r,v,m){
    this.x = width/2;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
   this.v = v;
   this.m = m;
   this.a = -10;
}
  
  veloci(){
    this.y = this.y+this.v
  }
  show(){
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r,this.r);
  }
  
  reverse(){
   this.v = -this.v 
  }
  
  // floor
  piso(){    
     return (this.y >= height)
  }
  
  // collide  
  choca(other){
   return !(this.y+this.r< other.y ||this.y> other.y+other.r) 
  }
  
  // bounce
  rebota(other) {
    let sumM = this.m + other.m;
    let newV = (this.m - other.m) / sumM * this.v;
    newV += (2 * other.m / sumM) * other.v;
    return newV;
  }
  
  display() {
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 500);
  bola1 = new Bola(450,50,3,1);
  bola2 = new Bola(350,50,3,1);
  bola3 = new Bola(250,50,3,1);
  bola4 = new Bola(150,50,3,1);
  bola5 = new Bola(50,50,3,1);
}

function draw() {
  background(110,20,20);
 
  // Show and update velocity for each ball
  // I would like to find a better way to handle these
  bola1.show();
  bola1.veloci();
  bola2.show();
  bola2.veloci();
  bola3.show();
  bola3.veloci();
  bola4.show();
  bola4.veloci();
  bola5.show();
  bola5.veloci();
 
  // Make the ball bounce when it hits the floor
  if (bola1.piso()) {
      bola1.reverse(); 
  }
 
  // Attempt to make balls bounce when they collide with each other
  if (bola1.choca(bola2)){
    const v1 = bola1.rebota(bola2);
    const v2 = bola2.rebota(bola1);
    bola1.v = v1;
    bola2.v = v2;
  }
  
  if (bola2.choca(bola3)){
    const v3 = bola2.rebota(bola3);
    const v4 = bola3.rebota(bola2);
    bola2.v = v3;
    bola3.v = v4;
  }
  
  if (bola3.choca(bola4)){
    const v5 = bola3.rebota(bola4);
    const v6 = bola4.rebota(bola3);
    bola3.v = v5;
    bola4.v = v6;
  }
  if (bola4.choca(bola5)){
    const v7 = bola4.rebota(bola5);
    const v8 = bola5.rebota(bola4);
    bola4.v = v7;
    bola5.v = v8;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

you can also see the code here:
https://editor.p5js.org/yogurtcongelado/sketches/mxEJxtsU_

(if you know how can I use separated folders in p5 because if I try to use another one for my classes the main program says the objects are not defined)

Comment: I think you will get a better answer if you trim your question down. For coding practices it looks like you can create an array and then in draw loop through the array and call show and viloci on each object. That said the complicated part seems to be the interaction between the objects. I don't understand the code inside if bola.choca for example.. can you describe in words what you want to happen?

Comment: going a little deeper into the code the choca function seems to be trying to detect collisions but the logic needs some work. Collision detection is a pretty big topic. For this code I recommend trying to get it to work for perhaps one object and the floor and then for two objects. You might want to take a look at this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652942/1978785

Comment: Another answer that might help you is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172674/1978785 This one does not handle interaction between balls but it does show how to simulate free fall under gravity.